# Getting Auto Increment multiple times

Tags: php, mysql

I'm hoping someone can help me figure out what I thought would be really easy.

I have a form that I dynamically add rows to.  When I add the row, I want to display a unique value, and am using the MySql table primary key - called ID.  Because there will be multiple users, I want to immediately reserve that ID, so it doesn't get reused.  Since a user may decide to add another item to the list, and add another dynamic row, I want to repeat the process (get the new Auto Increment value from that table, and immediately reserve it).

Unfortunately, I continue to get the same ID value, even though I have confirmed the auto increment value has increased.

This is what I am using inside my "add row" function before I use the DOM Element to add the row:

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'table'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$nextId = $row['Auto_increment'];   

$query = "INSERT INTO table (id, identifier1, identifier2) VALUES ('".$nextId."','".$identifier1."','".$identifier2."')";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

I have tried adding immediately before them the following in the hopes that it will blank everything and pull all new values:

```
$nextId = 0;
$row = "";
$result = "";
$query = "";
```

I am hoping someone out there can see something simple or suggest a better way that will work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you absolutely have to know the new ID before performing the `INSERT`? If not, then use `mysql_insert_id()` and return that value to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok as your comment shows you have a slight mistake in your INSERT, try this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table (identifier1, identifier2) 
          VALUES ('".$identifier1."','".$identifier2."')"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
$nextId = mysql_insert_id()+1; //you also need to +1 to get the next number
```

But there is NO guarentee that the next id will be +1 from the last.

Comment: I changed those value names for posting...They are gathered earlier, and are valid.  They are inserted, but that's not the issue.  Also, the ID primary key in the database is auto_increment.  I took the first three rows from another post here on SO.  What I want is not the last id added, but the NEXT value available in the table.  It won't always be last_insert_id + 1 because another user may have added one in between for another unit.

Comment: @WillSam see my edits i believe this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I also need to _reserve_ that number when I get it.  The concern is that if someone else came along and was getting the next number, while the form with this number is being filled, I want them to be different numbers...  I have also played with `$query = "INSERT INTO table (id, identifier1, identifier2) VALUES ('','".$identifier1."','".$identifier2."')";
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
 $nextId = mysql_insert_id();`
but I still get the same number coming up every time I add a new row.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the field is auto_increment and set to primary key? If so i don't know why you are adding `id` to your insert the point of auto increment is it does the job for you. Infact assigning an id to a primary key with auto increment manually with SQL is just a very bad idea.

Comment: @WillSam the mistake was your insert was slightly incorrect please see my edited answer :)

Comment: I appreciate your help.  Yes, absolutely certain auto_increment and Primary.  Even triple-checked that.  And fair enough, if I simply just insert to the table the two fields (no id), I still only get back the first id added, not new ones as I add each row.

Comment: You already have the values of the row you just inserted assigned in your two variables so you don't need to query that though.

Comment: Those two Identifiers simply associate this new entry to broader tables.  There are other values that will be inserted to this id row once the form is filled out.  Really all I want (with the revised code in comments), is the id every time I insert something.  If I do it twice, I get the same value back...  I would think that if I insert twice, retrieving the value after each one, the second should be the next available number...  And +1 will not always work, so cant' go that route.

Comment: Actually, continuing to debug.  It's just simply not adding the row to the table the second time I add the dynamic row.  The PHP code is inside the javascript function, which triggers, and adds all elements.  It's just simply this value I want to get pushed in there.  And I have identified a js variable by echoing the PHP value.  It works for the first dynamic row - so that's good.  It has something to do with the insert the second time around...

Comment: It seems your question will need more to get to the bottom of the answer.

Comment: @WillSam you might as well close this question.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, and I have tried to find the answer.  How do I "close" the question?  I have a few that might need this done to...  Thanks.